# Wordpress permalink not working after upgrading to OSX El Capitan

Tags: wordpress, macos, apache2, osx-elcapitan

I just upgraded my `OSX` to `El` Capitan and it messed up my `apache` environment.
I am running my projects in `/Users/username/Sites`.

After the upgrade I found out that `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` was reset to `default` so I had to setup again by following this [Link](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite/)

But after fixing the configurations, when I tried accessing the `wordpress` site, the permalink is not working anymore.

The top page and admin page is working. But when I navigate to other page, it's not working and I am getting this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /en/ was not found on this server.
>
> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /workshop was not found on this server.

I already tried to update the permalink. I checked my .htaccess and it's writable. But still, the permalink won't work.

Comment: Okay i think i fixed it. I also had to uncomment these lines in http.conf: 1. LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
 2. LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: Thank you so much Taiga: I had exactly the same issue. Your fix (uncommenting those lines in http.conf) worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I think the one step that guide missed is to add this in your vhost:

```
<Directory /Users/username/sites>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Without the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive, the .htaccess file in your site's WordPress directory will be ignored.

You will also need to enable the Rewrite module as you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Thank you! You're answer might help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally fix this issue in my MacOS Catalina. And what really worked for me was. Making changes to **/etc/httpd/httpd.conf** file. Making Override **none** to **All** and furthermore following @CodeDiary user's instructions and uncommenting following 2 lines of code from the same file.

1. LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
2. LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so